# Current year, specific day and specifc month - PHP

Tags: php, string, date, date-math

I want compare two dates but something is wrong.

My code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$hoje = date("Y/m/d");
$data_mudanca = date("Y")."-10-24";

echo 'Today: '.$hoje.'<br>';
echo 'ChangeDay: '.$data_mudanca.'<br>';

if($hoje > $data_mudanca){
    echo 'Today is bigger';
}else{
    echo 'ChangeDay is bigger';
}

?>
```

My result:

Today: 2015/10/23
ChangeDay: 2015-10-24
Today is bigger

---

but Today is not bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Your dates are not in the same format, much less a comparable one. Either use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects which are comparable, or put them in `YYYY-MM-DD` string format which is also comparable:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$hoje = new DateTime();
$data_mudanca = new DateTime(date("Y")."-10-24");

if($hoje > $data_mudanca){
    echo 'Today is bigger';
}else{
    echo 'ChangeDay is bigger';
}

?>
```

or

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$hoje = date("Y-m-d");
$data_mudanca = date("Y")."-10-24";

if($hoje > $data_mudanca){
    echo 'Today is bigger';
}else{
    echo 'ChangeDay is bigger';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks John Conde! :)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to compare date strings. Either use DateTime, or compare the timestamps, but not the date strings.

Answer (score 2):

Add strtotime() php function

```
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
    $hoje = strtotime(date("Y/m/d"));
    $data_mudanca = strtotime(date("Y")."-10-24");

    echo 'Today: '.$hoje.'<br>';
    echo 'ChangeDay: '.$data_mudanca.'<br>';

    if($hoje > $data_mudanca){
        echo 'Today is bigger';
    }else{
        echo 'ChangeDay is bigger';
    }

    ?>
```